# Adding a new column(group) to a data frame based on the two other data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

new to R. I want to add a new column to df1 based on df2 and df3

```
df1
ind t1 t2 
1 12 0.2
2 NA 0.3
3 9 0.3
4 11 0.4
5 11 0.3
6 10 0.4
7 14 0.3
```

df2 and df3 are subsets of df1

```
df2
ind t1
1 12
2 NA
3 9
```

```
df3
ind t1
4 11
7 14 
8 12
```

desired output

```
df1 
ind t1 t2 group
1 12 0.2 df2
2 NA 0.3 df2
3 9 0.3 df2
4 11 0.4 df3
5 11 0.3 NA
6 10 0.4 NA
7 14 0.3 df3
```

is there anyway to get the desired output using for loop with if statement?

Comment: Type `?merge` in R please.

Comment: `merge(df1, rbind(df2, df3), all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi welcome to so please provide a dput() but you can do

```
library(tidyverse)

df_class <- bind_rows(df2,df3)

df_result <- df_1 %>% 
  left_join(df_class)
```